# How do I create a drop down menu and make contents drop?

Tags: java, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having issues creating a dropdown menu using the a tag. I'm not sure why, but the drop down menu isn't working at all/doesn't seem to register. When the dropdown menu shows, I would like it to make the contents beneath drop down as well. Any help on this?

```
    <body>

        <div ID = "contents">
        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "origami main.html#about">About</a>

    <div ID = "dropDown">
        <a ID = "dropDownPortfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <div ID = "dropDownCnt">
            <a ID = "portfolioPortrait" href = "origami main.html#portraits">Portraits</a>
            <a ID = "portfolioPortrait" href = "origami main.html#stationary">Stationary Cards</a>
        </div>
    </div>

        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "">Video</a>

        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "">Contact</a>
        </div>

    </body>



  <style>
        
        a, #dropDown {
        color: #ff80d5;
        font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        }

        #contents{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        width: 50%;
        margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
        }

        #dropDownCnt{
            display: none;
            position:absolute;

        }

    </style>
```

Comment: add your code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on hover over #dropDown then expend #dropDownCnt

add this at the end

```
#dropDownCnt {
    max-height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
  }
  #dropDown:hover #dropDownCnt{
    max-height: 100px;
    visibility: visible;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

and remove this

```
#dropDownCnt{
            display: none;
            position:absolute;

        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked and did exactly what I was hoping it would do. Would you be able to let me know what max-height and transition properties do?

Comment: transition properties we use for animation we can divide in three parts. first "all" mean all properties we want to animate. we can define many properties like width, height, opacity max-height to animate those properties. second one is how animation function like ease, linear, ease-in, ease-out, ease-in-out, and cubic-bezier. last one is how long this animation will last. sorry for my bad english. [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

Comment: we use max-height, max-width, min-height, min-width for define minimum and maximum width and height for any element. if we use normal height and width properties to animate element's width and height properties it does not work instead we use max-height, max width properties to animate element width and height properties. Read More[max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width) and [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add hover state to your style

```
  a#dropDownPortfolio:hover +  #dropDownCnt{
      display:block;
   }
```

```css
 <style>
        
        a, #dropDown {
        color: #ff80d5;
        font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        }

        #contents{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        width: 50%;
        margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
        }

        #dropDownCnt{
            display: none;
            

        }
        
        a#dropDownPortfolio:hover +  #dropDownCnt{
          display:block;
        }

    </style>
```

```html
<body>

        <div ID = "contents">
        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "origami main.html#about">About</a>

    <div ID = "dropDown">
        <a ID = "dropDownPortfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <div ID = "dropDownCnt">
            <a ID = "portfolioPortrait" href = "origami main.html#portraits">Portraits</a>
            <a ID = "portfolioPortrait" href = "origami main.html#stationary">Stationary Cards</a>
        </div>
    </div>

        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "">Video</a>

        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "">Contact</a>
        </div>

    </body>



  <style>
        
        a, #dropDown {
        color: #ff80d5;
        font-family: Gill Sans, sans-serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 25px;
        }

        #contents{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        height: 30%;
        width: 50%;
        margin: -15% 0 0 -25%;
        }

        #dropDownCnt{
            display: none;
            position:absolute;

        }

    </style><body>

        <div ID = "contents">
        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "origami main.html#about">About</a>

    <div ID = "dropDown">
        <a ID = "dropDownPortfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <div ID = "dropDownCnt">
            <a ID = "portfolioPortrait" href = "origami main.html#portraits">Portraits</a>
            <a ID = "portfolioPortrait" href = "origami main.html#stationary">Stationary Cards</a>
        </div>
    </div>

        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "">Video</a>

        <a ID = "menuPage" href = "">Contact</a>
        </div>

    </body>
```